Recursive CTE and performance issue when anchor member is a large table
I have made some edits so that the post is clearer.
I have a large table  with data like below.

The goal is to be able to retrieve the original ID and location associated with the original ID given any ID as input. For example, if I were to look for ID 2,4,9, the result should be

Two questions:
1)How do I add to this script a column that represents the number of separation degree an ID  from the original ID? for example, ID 2 would be 0 (original/parent), ID 4 would be 2 and ID 9 would be 1 (it takes 3 IDs to get to original location)
--This question is answered by @ValNik
Here is a simplified script I used:
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (
  ID INTEGER
  ,PreviousID INTEGER
  ,Location INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO @IDs
SELECT           2,null,1235
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,1236
UNION ALL SELECT 4,3,1239
UNION ALL SELECT 8,null,1237
UNION ALL SELECT 9,8,1234
UNION ALL SELECT 10,9,1235

Select * from @IDs


DECLARE @ORDERID Table (OrderID nvarchar (100))
Insert into @ORDERID values
('4')
,('9')
,('2')

;WITH q AS (
    SELECT  ID, PreviousID,Location
    FROM    @IDs
    where ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID) 
       -- or PreviousID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID)
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  q.ID, u.PreviousID,q.Location
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN @IDs u ON u.ID = q.PreviousID
            --and q.ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID)
)


,CTE_Original as
(
SELECT  q.ID
        ,q.Location
        ,case when Min(PreviousID) is null then ID
                else min(PreviousID) end as OriginalID

FROM    q
GROUP BY q.ID,q.Location
)

Select CTE_Original.*,Original.Location as OriginalLocation from CTE_Original 
left join @IDs Original on Original.ID = CTE_Original.OriginalID
                        
where CTE_Original.ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID)
order by ID


In real life, @IDs is a temporary table with 3M+ rows that originated from joining a couple tables. The equivalence of @IDs in the example above is #CTE_ORDERID. It takes about 20s to insert values to generate CTE_ORDERID and insert them to #CTE_ORDERID. However, the recursive CTE q takes >10 mins. What can I do in order to have better performance? I don't have access to execution plan.

Here is the script
DECLARE @ORDERID Table (OrderID nvarchar (100))
Insert into @ORDERID values
('119309645')
,('115821862')
,('112942594')

;


Drop table if exists #CTE_OrderID

;
;WITH CTE_OrderID AS (
    SELECT ORDER_MED.ORDER_MED_ID as CURRENT_ORDERID
        ,ORDER_MED.CHNG_ORDER_MED_ID as PREV_ORDERID
        ,CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_NAME    as WRITTEN_LOCATION
        ,ORDER_MED.ORDERING_DATE        as WRITTEN_DATE
    FROM Clarity_PRD_Report.dbo.ORDER_MED (nolock)  
        LEFT JOIN Clarity_PRD_Report.dbo.CLARITY_DEP (nolock) on ORDER_MED.PAT_LOC_ID = CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID
    GROUP BY ORDER_MED_ID --,PAT.PAT_MRN_ID
        ,ORDER_MED.CHNG_ORDER_MED_ID
        ,CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_NAME    
        ,ORDERING_DATE  
        )
Select * 
Into #CTE_OrderID
From CTE_OrderID
;
With q as (
    Select CURRENT_ORDERID
           ,PREV_ORDERID
           ,PREV_ORDERID as Last_ORDERID
           ,WRITTEN_LOCATION
           ,WRITTEN_LOCATION as ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_LOCATION
           ,WRITTEN_DATE
           ,WRITTEN_DATE as ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_DATE
           ,0 NumOfTimesRewrite
           
           
    From #CTE_OrderID
        where CURRENT_ORDERID in (Select OrderID from @ORDERID) 

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  q.CURRENT_ORDERID
            ,u.PREV_ORDERID
            ,q.PREV_ORDERID LAST_ORDERID
            ,q.WRITTEN_LOCATION
            ,u.WRITTEN_LOCATION
            ,q.WRITTEN_DATE
            ,u.WRITTEN_DATE
            ,NumOfTimesRewrite+1

    FROM    q
            inner JOIN #CTE_OrderID u ON u.CURRENT_ORDERID = q.PREV_ORDERID
            --and q.ORDER_MED_ID in (select orderID from @ORDERID)
)

Select CURRENT_ORDERID
    ,Coalesce(LAST_ORDERID,CURRENT_ORDERID) as ORIGINAL_ORDERID
    ,WRITTEN_LOCATION
    ,ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_LOCATION
    ,WRITTEN_DATE
    ,ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_DATE
    ,NumOfTimesRewrite

FROM q
WHERE PREV_ORDERID is null
order by CURRENT_ORDERID

I appreciate any help on this!

Can you limit the recursive depth? If it is max 3 levels deep then this allows you to rewrite this query as a union of 3 queries and avoid any recursion.

No levels are not just 3. it can be 7 or 8 or more

If you have less than 100 levels it shouldn't error out, then there's a bug in your code or perhaps bad data

Or, perhaps you have circular references?

That is true. I will check on it. But the part that I am very curious about is how to create a CTE that would limit the table @ID to just relevant information needed to arrive at the answers related to the values listed in @ORDERID. When @ID is raw, it is simply too large to process efficiently with the CTE q

Several questions: 1.Condition or PreviousID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID) in anchor part creates extra lines in the anchor part. At least doubles the size of the request. 2. Condition and q.ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID) in recursive part is superfluous.  3. How do you check for circular references?

Please do not use images for data, use table markdown

@ThienPham well, you can't limit it, because that's the point of the hierarchy, that the node path isn't completely known, only the parent. But most recursive CTEs can be written as a loop, so if you're scared of performance, a properly indexed #t-table and a loop should have no problem to handle a couple of millions of rows

@ValNik. Thank you for point (1) and (2). I agree and I believe you have adjusted the post. 3) I have checked, there are no circular references (no ID corresponds with the same value in PreviousID)

Circular reference my be thru several rows. For example (Id,PreviousId) (5,4)(4,3),(3,5) - circle. Question is - Is possible circular reference by construction?

@Siggermannen, your comment that one cannot limit @IDs ahead of time because the node path is not completely know seems to make sense.  May I ask how does a loop for this case would look like instead of a recursive CTE and is there a distinct advantage to looping instead of recursive CTE?

@ValNik. I just check my script, I believe the 100 recursion was the result of a mistake I had, not an issue with the table construction. All the IDs eventually lead to an ID whose previous ID is null.

@Dale K, I have the table of sample data in the code as well. In this case, is the image of the table still not acceptable?

There would be no advantage to a loop. Unless your data was crazy tiny, a recursive CTE is the right way to define what will be ran as a loop at an execution layer that is closely coupled with the data to get the most bang for your performance buck. With the circular reference issue fixed in your SQL, are you getting results back now or still erroring?

Images are not acceptable no

See simple example, without check for circular references.
If you have circular references, you mast throw error, or stop on that node. Or you can hope that you don't have cycles in table:). Or do additional check the path through the nodes.
WITH q AS (
    SELECT 0 lvl,  ID, PreviousID,PreviousID LastId
        ,Location,Location as OriginalLocation
    FROM    @IDs
    where ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT lvl+1, q.ID,u.PreviousId,q.PreviousId LastId
       ,q.Location,u.Location
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN @IDs u ON u.ID = q.PreviousID
)
select lvl, ID, coalesce(LastId,Id) OriginalId,Location,OriginalLocation 
from q
where PreviousId is null
order by id;

Output is



lvl
ID
OriginalId
Location
OriginalLocation




0
2
2
1235
1235


2
4
2
1239
1235


1
9
8
1234
1237



Before filter



lvl
ID
PreviousID
LastId
Location
OriginalLocation




0
2
null
null
1235
1235


0
4
3
3
1239
1239


1
4
2
3
1239
1236


2
4
null
2
1239
1235


0
9
8
8
1234
1234


1
9
null
8
1234
1237



fiddle
Update1. With your comment about source tables
see example
With q as (
  Select ORDER_MED_ID CURRENT_ORDERID
   ,CHNG_ORDER_MED_ID PREV_ORDERID
   ,CHNG_ORDER_MED_ID as Last_ORDERID          
   ,PAT_LOC_ID as WRITTEN_LOCATION_ID
   ,PAT_LOC_ID as ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_LOCATION_ID
   ,0 NumOfTimesRewrite                     
  From ORDER_MED        
  where ORDER_MED_ID in (4,9,2) -- (Select OrderID from @ORDERID)      
  UNION ALL      
  SELECT  q.CURRENT_ORDERID
   ,u.CHNG_ORDER_MED_ID PREV_ORDERID            
   ,q.PREV_ORDERID LAST_ORDERID             
   ,q.WRITTEN_LOCATION_ID
   ,u.PAT_LOC_ID ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_LOCATION_ID
   ,NumOfTimesRewrite+1      
  FROM q inner JOIN ORDER_MED u 
     ON u.ORDER_MED_ID = q.PREV_ORDERID          
)
Select CURRENT_ORDERID  
  ,Coalesce(LAST_ORDERID,CURRENT_ORDERID) as ORIGINAL_ORDERID   
  ,WRITTEN_LOCATION_ID  
  ,ORIGINAL_WRITTEN_LOCATION_ID
  ,NumOfTimesRewrite
  ,d1.department_name written_location
  ,d2.department_name original_written_location
from q
left join clarity_dep d1 on d1.department_id=q.written_location_id
left join clarity_dep d2 on d2.department_id=q.original_written_location_id
where prev_orderid is null
order by q.current_orderid

Temporary tables not necessary.
Demo fiddle

Thank you @ValNik! This is exactly what I was looking for. I still have a performance issue in live environment. The @IDs table contains ~3M rows which took only 20s to retrieve and be inserted to a temp table. However, the Recursive CTE q took upward of 9 minutes to complete for an output of only 3 records, for which the max number of recursion is 3. Do you see why this might be the case?

Do you have index on (Id)? Perhaps - not( temporary table). What is performance for simple query select id from yourtable where id=<some existing id value>?  Why are you using a temporary table? You can retrieve these 3 row directly from source table.

In my test table with 2M rows and recursion depth near 10, execution time 2s without index and 100ms with index.

You can update question. This is more readable format. I think, there several incomprehensible places in the queries. First, grouping in CTE_OrderId-? . Second, Join Departments may be in final part of query. Use Department_id instead Department_name.

I was able to implement what you suggested and performance was instantly better without the temporary table. May I ask, why is there such a huge performance difference? Is it because the temporary table is not indexed?

If you do not consider the cost of copying to a temporary table. If the temporary table does not have an index and statistics, then each iteration of the recursive query will require scanning the temporary table, i.e. reading about 1.5M rows. If there is an index, you will need to search by index (index only scan) and read log(3M)=18 readings. That will be the difference in performance. Your permanent table probably has an index and up-to-date statistics, so an optimal query execution plan will be drawn up.

@DaleK, I forgot the step. Thanks for the reminder.
