Recursive CTE and how to overcome circular reference error
I have a script that is meant to find the original Location.
It starts with a table like this:



ID
PreviousID
Location




2
NULL
1235


3
2
1236


4
3
1239


8
11
1237


9
8
1234


10
9
1235


11
10
1237



I want to find the original Location for a select number of ID values



ID




2


4


8


10


11



The result I am looking for is:



lvl
ID
OriginalId
Location
OriginalLocation




0
2
2
1235
1235


2
4
2
1239
1235


0
8
8
1237
1237


2
10
8
1235
1237


3
11
8
1237
1237



The output for ID =2 and =4 is good.
However, with 8,10,11, this result in circular reference and the code breaks.
Question: Is there away to address this issue so that the error does not occur:

The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

and produce the desired outputs? I know 8 is the root since it is the smallest number in that chain even though there is circular reference in that chain.
Here is the script that I have so far to produce output for ID 2 and 4. It works if you remove value 8,10,11
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (
  ID INTEGER
  ,PreviousID INTEGER
  ,Location INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO @IDs
SELECT           2,null,1235
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,1236
UNION ALL SELECT 4,3,1239
UNION ALL SELECT 8,11,1237
UNION ALL SELECT 9,8,1234
UNION ALL SELECT 10,9,1235
UNION ALL SELECT 11,10,1237

Select * from @IDs


DECLARE @ORDERID Table (OrderID nvarchar (100))
Insert into @ORDERID values
('2')
,('4')
--,('8')
--,('10')
--,('11')

;WITH q AS (
    SELECT 0 lvl,  ID, PreviousID,PreviousID LastId
        ,Location,Location as OriginalLocation
    FROM    @IDs
    where ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT lvl+1, q.ID,u.PreviousId,q.PreviousId LastId
       ,q.Location,u.Location
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN @IDs u ON u.ID = q.PreviousID
            --and q.ID <> u.PreviousID and q.PreviousID <> u.ID
)
select lvl, ID, coalesce(LastId,Id) OriginalId,Location,OriginalLocation 
from q
where PreviousId is null
order by id;

Thank you very much for any hint or suggestion.

@DaleK, 8 is the root because it is the smallest number in that chain

It did not. I will add. thank you.

@DaleK, may I ask how did you reformat the table such that looks nice like it is now?

Will valid previous values always have descending IDs?  Or might you have a weird up-and-down sequence like 23 -> 21 -> 22 -> 24 -> 20 -> 26 -> 25, where the desired answer id 20?

Aside: If ID is a surrogate key, e.g. an identity column, then you generally shouldn't be ascribing any additional meaning to it. If you have a requirement that ID values only increase over time or have some other property then you should: (1) document the requirement and (b) contemplate using a more appropriate name rather than the initials for inside diameter.

You were mostly there... you just needed to make two changes:

Add an additional join condition q.ID > u.Id to stop when you get to the smallest Id.
Calculate which results to show to include those that had a recusion. I found it clearer to add a specific calculation to determine the root then to complicate the where clause logic.

WITH q AS (
    SELECT 0 lvl
        , ID
        , PreviousID
        , PreviousID LastId
        , Location
        , Location AS OriginalLocation
        , CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN PreviousID IS NULL OR PreviousId > Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsRoot
    FROM @IDs
    WHERE ID in (select OrderID from @ORDERID) 
  
    UNION ALL 
  
    SELECT lvl + 1
        , q.ID
        , u.PreviousId
        , q.PreviousId LastId
        , q.Location
        , u.Location
        , CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN u.PreviousID IS NULL OR u.PreviousId > u.Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsRoot
    FROM q
    INNER JOIN @IDs u ON u.ID = q.PreviousID
        -- Ensure we stop at the lowest Id
        AND q.ID > u.Id
)
SELECT lvl, ID, coalesce(LastId,Id) OriginalId, Location, OriginalLocation
FROM q
WHERE IsRoot = 1
ORDER BY id;

DBFiddle

wow this is elegant. Thank you. What is the advantage of convert in this case?

Nothing actually :) I'm just used to converting to a bit so that in client code it arrives as a bool rather than an int. But you can totally take it out for this case.

Suggested tweaks: (1) Change OR PreviousId > Id to OR PreviousId => Id in the IsRoot calculation (both places) to handle a self-loop case like 12 -> 12*. (2) If #1 is applied, the CTE terminating condition AND q.ID > u.Id could then be replaced with WHERE q.IsRoot = 0. This would also handle a case like 23 -> 22 -> 21 -> 22*, where a loop is entirely below the original ID.

@TN, can you leave your other suggested solution up? It was there a couple of days ago but I think you removed it now. I am running into issue with my live data  where recursion error is hitting 100 max still. I would like to use your suggested solution to trouble shoot where things might have gone wrong

@T340B just put a recursion limit on your cte and remove the filter - that's how to debug it, because you will see every calculation.

@T340B. - You can also try applying the two suggested modifications that I posted yesterday (16:17 on 28 June). This fixes a few cases that would still cause unlimited recursion. With those changes in place, all scenarios should reach a terminal condition. Fiddle.

As noted in the comments below, this does not produce the OP's desired "smallest number" result. I am leaving it posted for now, pending further discussion and possible improvement. The other posted answer may be the best simplest answer.
I am going to assume a general case, where the ID order has no significance, and the sequence of PreviousID values may arbitrarily jump up and down. I will also allow for cases where the sequence may progress linearly before dropping into a loop that might or might not include the original ID value.
One way to detect loops is to build a list of visited ID values and check each new ID against the visited ID list. Since SQL Server doesn't have arrays or similar multi-valued types, we can fall back onto a comma-separated list of visited IDs stored as a string. That list would be initialized with the original ID value and additional IDs would be appended in the recursive part of the CTE. An appropriately-delimited CHARINDEX() test could check if we have reached a previously visited ID.
Something like:
WITH q AS (
    SELECT
        0 lvl, ID, PreviousID, PreviousID LastId
        ,Location, Location as OriginalLocation
        ,CAST(CONCAT(',', ID, ',') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as VisitedIDs
        ,CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS LoopDetected
    FROM    IDs
    where ID in (select OrderID from ORDERID) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT lvl+1, q.ID,u.PreviousId,q.PreviousId LastId
       ,q.Location,u.Location
       ,CONCAT(VisitedIDs, u.ID, ',')
       ,CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', u.ID, ','), VisitedIDs) AS LoopDetected
    FROM    q
    INNER JOIN IDs u ON u.ID = q.PreviousID
    WHERE q.LoopDetected = 0
)
select lvl, ID, coalesce(LastId,Id) OriginalId,Location,OriginalLocation
    , q.LoopDetected, q.VisitedIDs
    , CASE WHEN q.LoopDetected > 0 THEN 'Loop detected' ELSE '' END AS ErrorCheck
from q
where (PreviousId is null OR q.LoopDetected > 0)
order by id, lvl;

Note that the CHARINDEX() test wraps the ID value with commas to ensure for example that ID = 5 only matches ...,5,... and not ...,15,... or ...,51,.... The VisitedIDs also has extra commas to support this test.
Sample results (with some extra test data):



lvl
ID
OriginalId
Location
OriginalLocation
LoopDetected
VisitedIDs
ErrorCheck




0
2
2
1235
1235
0
,2,



2
4
2
1239
1235
0
,4,3,2,



4
8
8
1237
1237
1
,8,11,10,9,8,
Loop detected


4
10
10
1235
1235
1
,10,9,8,11,10,
Loop detected


4
11
11
1237
1237
1
,11,10,9,8,11,
Loop detected


8
12
10
9999
1235
11
,12,5,13,6,10,9,8,11,10,
Loop detected


3
23
22
9999
9999
0
,23,21,24,22,




If you want to avoid creating a list, you can track a sample prior ID (initially the starting ID) and check each step against that tracked ID. The problem is that a loop might be reached that not include the original ID. To handle this case, you can reset the tracked ID at increasing intervals (powers of 2) so that when a loop is entered, the tracked ID will eventually be reset so that the loop will eventually be detected.
WITH q AS (
    SELECT
        0 lvl, ID, PreviousID, PreviousID LastId
        ,Location, Location as OriginalLocation
        ,ID as LoopCheckID
    FROM    IDs
    where ID in (select OrderID from ORDERID) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT lvl+1, q.ID,u.PreviousId,q.PreviousId LastId
       ,q.Location,u.Location
       ,CASE WHEN lvl & (lvl - 1) = 0 THEN u.ID ELSE q.LoopCheckID END
    FROM    q
    INNER JOIN IDs u ON u.ID = q.PreviousID
    WHERE q.PreviousID <> q.LoopCheckID
)
select lvl, ID, coalesce(LastId,Id) OriginalId,Location,OriginalLocation
    , q.PreviousID, q.LoopCheckID
    , CASE WHEN q.PreviousID = q.LoopCheckID THEN 'Loop detected' ELSE '' END AS ErrorCheck
from q
where (PreviousId is null OR q.PreviousID = q.LoopCheckID)
order by id, lvl;

The lvl & (lvl - 1) = 0 is a tricky bit manipulation check that is true when lvl is a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...).
Sample results:



lvl
ID
OriginalId
Location
OriginalLocation
PreviousID
LoopCheckID
ErrorCheck




0
2
2
1235
1235
null
2



2
4
2
1239
1235
null
2



8
8
8
1237
1237
11
11
Loop detected


8
10
10
1235
1235
9
9
Loop detected


8
11
11
1237
1237
10
10
Loop detected


8
12
10
9999
1235
9
9
Loop detected


3
23
22
9999
9999
null
22




Note that in several cases above, the loop detection occurred several steps later than in the earlier list-based solution.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo of both of the above techniques.
One other possible approach would be check the entire IDs table in advance to identify which IDs are reachable (in the reverse direction) from rows having PreviousID = null. Once that list is built, any IDs not in that list would be known to be part of a loop. (I have not coded up this approach.)

That doesn't produce OPs desired results however... they specified that the loop should end on the lowest ID visited, not when it gets back to itself.

@DaleK - Good point. I didn't catch that. Might need to track MIN(ID) during the process, and join back to that row in the final select. That would handle weird cases like 23 -> 21 -> 22 -> 24 -> 20 -> 26 -> 25, where we don't know the minimum until we hit the end.

While I admire your commitment to a generalised solution, I think its overkill for this and many other scenarios. SQL best practice is more focused on solving specific issues than building generic queries like you might in other coding languages. And I'm fairly sure I've seen the general solution to this answered before, so it would be a dup in that case.

@TN, your solution is interesting even if it does not produce the desired result. Your suggestion is of value for me. I still need some time to digest this though. Thank you.

Shouldn't CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', u.ID), VistiedIDs) AS LoopDetected be CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', u.ID, ','), VistiedIDs) AS LoopDetected? Otherwise ',5' can match ',42,55,9,'. And what is the meaning of Vistied?

@HABO - Yes. Thank you. That was what I intended - now fixed. By visited, I am referring to the ID values (rows) that have been encountered so far as the CTE traverses the linked list defined by the PreviousID values.

If you look at the OP's previous question on this topic, you can see that the transitions PreviousId->Id have a transition date. Given this date, there cycles may be broken. For example, from the chain (Id,Previous Id,Order Date) (1,null,'2024-06-01')(2,1,'2024-06-01'),(3,2,'2024-06-02'),(4,3,'2024-06-03'),(2,4,'2024-06-04') ,(5,2,'2024-06-05') definitely follows path 1-2-3-4-2-5 .  It would be useful to consider this issue taking into account the date. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78648963/recursive-cte-and-performance-issue-when-anchor-member-is-a-large-table)
